# How to access a variable from another JS file in webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, global-variables

I'm trying to implement webpack in a project, but can't seem to find a clear answer to this issue in their docs. I need to be able to access a certain variable globally from a JS file, for example:

toProps.js:

```
var myProp = "test";
```

In my entry point I do the following:

entry.js:

```
require('./toProps.js');
console.log(myProp);
```

But the variable `myProp` is undefined. This is an extremely simplified example, not my actual use case, but the point is that I'm working with an existing code base where there are these types of global references all over the place, but I want to implement some module and lazy loading with webpack.

How can I access the `myProp` variable?

Answer (score 5):

Inside `toProps.js`:

```
var myProp = "test";
export default myProp;
```

Inside `entry.js`:

```
import myProp from './toProps.js';
```

From what I see, you haven't exported the variable. Therefore, it can't be an 'import' inside `entry.js`.

Edit 1: Learn more about exporting [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export).

Edit 2:

Okay, to make it a global variable, here's what I did:

Move `props.js` into `/dist` and link it inside `index.html`, before `bundle.js`, or whatever you've named the output file.

Now it's a global variable, so you don't actually need to export or import it anywhere.

To test this, I made a file called `test.js`, imported it into `entry.js`. Inside `test.js` is:

```
const logTest = () => {
  console.log(myProp)
}
export default logTest;
```

Now inside `entry.js`, I invoked the function. It worked as expected and 'test' showed up in the console.

As you mentioned, your example is simplified, so this may not be viable for you. Maybe, you could move all the global variables to one file inside `/dist`, inside an object, as it's best not to pollute the global object.

Edit 3: Go with the answer from Jonas W. Totally forgot you could do that.

Comment: I see - but this isn't actually a global variable correct? I would have to import `myProp` to every file where I want to use it?

Answer (score 3):

If you really need a global variable (no you dont!), use `window`:

```
  window.myProp = "test";
```

Otherwise just export it from your file and import it everywhere you need it. That maybe adds some overhead to your code, but actually you always know where the value comes from, which makes debugging super simple.

Comment: I wish I didnt need global variables - but its a massive legacy code base with global declarations all over

Answer (score 1):

## Using webpack 4

To update this post for anyone that can read it, acctually you can use a plugin in **webpack.config.js** to resolve names that used in another .js files.

Take a look in https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/ example:

---

#### Usage: jQuery

To automatically load jquery we can simply point both variables it exposes to the corresponding node module:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery'
});
```

Then in any of our source code:

```
// in a module
$('#item'); // <= just works
jQuery('#item'); // <= just works
// $ is automatically set to the exports of module "jquery"
```

---

Comment: Why this post was received a down vote? This question needs a update answer!

Answer (score 0):

If the source file to import belongs to maintainer, it's best to export first and import latter. Just like the answer of @Ibrahim.

I also encounter a situation to **import third party source file just not using export syntax**. So I think below is a solution while using **webpack**.

First, install **exports-loader** for your project.

```
npm install exports-loader --save-dev
```

Then, in your JS source file, import and use like below:

```
const WEBGL = require("exports-loader?WEBGL!three/examples/js/WebGL.js");
WEBGL.isWebGL2Available()
```

In my case, *WEBGL* is the inner variable I wish to import, *three/examples/js/WebGL.js* is the third party source file.

Hoping this is useful.